# Passing Multiple Dates in Mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, stored-procedures

I am passing dates as comma separated values eg. param1 = 2012-01-12,2013-02-15,2012-12-01 and this will be input to my procedure and how can I get values of all the dates which are passed as parameter to my procedure.

I have tried using :  select value from table1 where date_value in (param1); but it is giving me a empty set.

Please tell me how to solve it.

Update:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION test2(dates text)
RETURNS text  READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE abc text;
DECLARE hi text;

SET hi= concat('''',regex_replace('[,]',''',''',dates),'''');

select value into abc from table1 where date_time in (hi);

RETURN abc;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

My Input to this function will be multiple dates: e.g: 2010-12-12,2012-12-10,.....

And My regex_replace function will return me the date in this format: '2010-12-12','2012-12-10' and setting this to a variable and passing it.

But I always get a empty set. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: try like this  param1 = "'2012-01-12','2013-02-15','2012-12-01'"

Comment: No it did not work. is there anything else which can be done ?

Comment: show your procedure and your procedure call please

Comment: hi added a function ,Please look into this.

Comment: CHANGE THIS date_time in (hi);  to date_time in (@hi); and see if it works

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do in your example is build SQL on the fly. This needs to be done with a [prepared statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). However, prepared statements cannot be used in functions and they are also a security risk if someone can manipulate the "dates" variable.

Instead, I would suggest splitting the dates variable and inserting the parts into a temp table and then querying against this. I have made a quick example below:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS checkCommaList;
DELIMITER #
CREATE FUNCTION checkCommaList(dates text)
RETURNS text
BEGIN

    DECLARE abc text;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS checkCommaListTemp;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE checkCommaListTemp(textToSearch text); 

    WHILE (LOCATE(',',dates) > 0)
    DO
        SET @found = SUBSTRING(dates, 1, LOCATE(',', dates) - 1 );
        SET dates = SUBSTRING(dates, LOCATE(',', dates) + 1);
        INSERT INTO checkCommaListTemp VALUES (@found);
    END WHILE;

    SELECT `value` INTO abc FROM table1 
        WHERE date_time IN (SELECT * FROM checkCommaListTemp);

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE checkCommaListTemp ;

    RETURN abc;

END;
#
DELIMITER ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE table1 (`value` text, date_time text);
INSERT INTO table1 (`value`, date_time) VALUES ('a', '2010-12-12');

SELECT checkCommaList('2010-12-12,2012-12-10');
```

There are probably more efficient methods of achieving what you want, however.

Comment: I was not allowed to use temporary tables so I have split the dates and stored them in different variables and achieved the same.